# Android setTextColor not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

i'm trying to colorize text in textView using:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
streetTv.setTextColor(color);
```

But this not working (i got null pointer exception)

But if i tried to:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

This works.

Where can be problem?

Comment: `streetTv` is initialized?

Comment: Check the import of R. It shouldn't be android.R

Comment: `setTextColor()` and `setBackgroundColor()` are not the same, one colors the text and the other colors the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use something like this:

```
 streetTv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); //or any other color available
```

i don't think you actually need the resources in your case, because you didn't mention so.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just set it directly.

```
streetTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

Also as Raghunandan said, did you initialize streetTv?

Comment: If you have loaded the textView from the layout, not just declared the textView as a variable, what @Aashir worked for me too

Answer (score -1):

have you declared

```
streetTv = findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
```

before changing background color.